# Mouse interaction in ListBoxItem children (WPF)

Tags: wpf, listbox, mouse, selection, listboxitem

I have a ListBox with an ItemTemplate that contains a control that interacts with the mouse. This interfers with the selection functionality of the ListBox, i.e. clicking a control does not select the item. This is because ListBoxItem sets the Handled property of the mouse event to true in OnMouseLeftButtonDown. I tried the following

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

but the ListBoxItem “takes over” the mouse and prevents the control from doing its own interaction. Then I had another idea

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    ((ListBoxItem)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this)))).IsSelected = true;
}
```

which actually works, but feels more like an ugly kludge than an elegant solution. Are there any better solutions that don't rely on the exact contents of the visual tree?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way that is less of a kludge:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    Selector.SetIsSelected(this, true);
}
```

For this to have any effect, the control in the ListBox' ItemTemplate needs the following XAML attribute:

```
Selector.IsSelected="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWayToSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
```

It raises two new questions:

1. Would it be better to define my own dependency property rather than finding an attached one that isn't currently in use?
2. Is there a way to achieve something similar in markup only?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MouseLeftButtonDown is a tunnelling event: you could try using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, doing your processing there, then ensuring e.Handled = false; as you tried already - that should do the trick!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but you have it backwards: MouseLeftButtonDown is the bubbling event and PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is the tunneling one. :) How would PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown improve the situation?

Comment: Preview events happen before the actual events: so if you did your processing in there, and then set e.Handled = false;, your code would get executed but the ListBox would still run its own handling code, for changing the selected item.  At least hopefully; that's how I understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution, but unfortunately handler can be attached only in code, not in markup.
Event handler can be added by using `handledEventsToo` signature of `AddHandler` method:

```
myListBox.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, 
        new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBox_MouseDown), true);
```

Third parameter above is `handledEventsToo` which ensures that this handler will be invoked no matter if it is already marked as `Handled` (which `ListBoxItem` does in ListBox).

See [**Marking Routed Events as Handled, and Class Handling**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx) for explanation.
See [**How to Attach to MouseDown Event on ListBox**](http://www.wpfnewbie.com/2010/07/22/how-to-attach-to-mousedown-event-on-listbox/)  for example.